# How to save simplexml node value to string?

Tags: php

I am trying to get a value in a node, and save it into a string variable. I haven't used PHP in about 5 years so I have no idea what is going on?

```
string $errorMessage = (string)$error->message);
print_r($errorMessage);
```

returns nothing

Comment: try `$errorMessage = (string)$error->message;`

Comment: You're missing an open brace in there...

Comment: or use $errorMessage = strval($error->message);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first do

```
$errorMessage = (string)$error->message;
```

and dont do print_r its used for echoing array simply use echo instead so

```
echo $errorMessage;
```

Php is not strongly typed language so you dont need to do `string $errorMessage;` , but still casting is pressent in php , coz objects such as simplexml implements __toString magic function which gets called automaticaly when you cast that object as string .